# What "Earth-Origin" animals exist in the canon Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, animals

When I was a young teen, I really got into reading the few Star Wars novels that existed at that time.  After I exhausted the then current run of books (there were only about 5 or 6 of them), I decided to read the novelizations of the original trilogy.

I no longer own those novels so I can't look up the reference, but I recall that during the beginning of A New Hope, when Luke and Obi-Wan rode into Mos Eisley on Luke's land speeder, Lucas mentioned something of there being a "dog barking".

This always struck me as odd because this was a reference to an animal from Earth in a universe where clearly most creatures were completely unique.

After noticing the reference to a dog I then noticed on my next viewing of ESB that there was a snake on Dagobah.

This has made me curious for years.  What other Earth-based creatures have made their way into the "official" Star Wars universe and where do they appear?

Comment: A snake on Dagobah was more likely to have been a result of convergent evolution than "Earth based"

Comment: relevant: http://xkcd.com/890/

Comment: Ummam...Humans?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- There are [ducks](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Duck) on Naboo in the movies.
- Also, in the scripting for Star Wars Obi-Wan said to Luke - "Still even a duck must be taught to swim." to which Luke said "what's a duck."
- Page 18 of ANH novelization ("*STAR WARS: From the adventures of Luke Skywalker*") :

  > Sandflies buzzed lazily in the cracked eaves of pourstone buildings. A dog barked in the distance...
- In the made-for-TV Ewoks movies ("*Caravan of Courage: An Ewok Adventure*" etc...), there are Earth [horses](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Horse)

  There are also other Earth animals on Endor as well from the same sources: Llama's, Ponies, etc...
- In ESB, there are Earth snakes and monitor lizards on Dagobah.
- Presumably, *Falcons* exist in TGFFA :)

All in all, I don't see how you find that surprising when the premise is that the dominant race in the Galaxy far far away are 100% human looking and are called "Humans".

Also, it's not impossible for [convergent evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution) to produce similar designs for similar environmental conditions.

Comment: I was thinking, "Made-for-TV? I'm *sure* I saw it in the cinema!" [Turns out we're both right...](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087225/releaseinfo)

Answer (score 14):

In light of recent developments in the *Star Wars* canon, I'll add an updated answer.

- Humans:

[image: Humans]

- Snakes:

[image: Snakes]

- Lizards:

[image: Lizards]

- In the canon novel *Lords of the Sith*, Sidious uses the "like
  [rats](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rat) from a sinking ship" simile. They are also shown in *Return
  of the Jedi* and are mentioned in other works.

[image: Rats]

- [Alderaanian wolf-cats](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Alderaanian_wolf-cat) and Endor [Boar-Wolves](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boar-wolf) exist, implying
  that  wolves, cats and boars exist.
- [Rabbits](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rabbit/Canon).
- [Bats](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bat).
- [Dogs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dog).
- [Fish](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fish).
- [Fireflies](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Firefly):

[image: Fireflies]

- [Frogs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Frog/Canon).

Comment: Wookies come from the Pacific Northwest, under different names, of course.  And I'm pretty sure that Ewoks come from Build-A-Bear.

Answer (score 8):

I looked through my Kindle editions of all the canonical books I own, and found the following words;  I have taken the liberty of providing links for the few entries on the list that might be unfamiliar to some people:

---

### *Star Wars:  A New Hope* novelization:

Dogs
Cats
Moths
Rodents; mice
Insects
Bees
Vultures
Crows
Lizards (although they are "enormous" and have eight legs and huge tusks)
Elephants

---

### *Tarkin*:

Birds;  vultures
Fish
Rodents
Insects; ants;  [stinging ants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_venom)
Felines
Crustaceans
Canines
Reptiles; serpents (which "rattle... in forewarning" - i.e., rattlesnakes); [vipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viperidae)

---

### *Aftermath*:

Dogs
Cats
Rats
Pigs
Birds;  hawks;  chickens; peacocks
Fish
Snakes;  [vine snakes](http://www.britannica.com/animal/vine-snake); venomous snakes;  [adders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder); vipers
Moths
Butterflies
Monkeys
Ants
Wasps
Spiders;  [Assassin spiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaeidae)
Bulls
Lizards (in reference to monkey-lizards)
Amphibians

---

### *So You Want to Be a Jedi?*:

Snakes
Dogs
Cats
Lizards (although this refers to Tauntauns)
Birds;  chickens
Fish; [silver-fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_fish_(fish)); sharks
Frogs (mentioned several times, all but once referring to Yoda :) )
Mice
Tigers
Rabbits
Cows
Toads
Flies
Sheep
Bats (Mynocks have "batlike" faces)
Spiders
Gorillas (The Wampa is compared to one)
Polar Bears (The Wampa is compared to one)

---

### *A New Dawn*:

Rodents
Fish
Insects; bugs
Monkeys
Slugs (albeit space slugs)

---

### *Heir to the Jedi*:

Dogs
Cats
Birds; [carrion birds](http://birding.about.com/od/birdingglossary/g/glosscarrion.htm)
Amphibians
Insects
Fish
Slugs
Snakes
Scorpions
Spiders
Mammals
Eels

---

### *Smugglers Run*

Birds; [birds of prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_of_prey); [shrikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrike)
Insects
Fish

---

### *The Weapon of a Jedi*:

Birds
Insects; bugs

Comment: Good answer, but I'd quibble with the inclusion of the New Hope novelization--[novelizations prior to The Force Awakens are not considered canonical](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/712038897065304067) when they present any new information that wasn't shown in the movie.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Only one of those on there.  Maybe two.

Comment: Maybe animals mentioned by the narrator shouldn't count? Animals mentioned in comparisons and figurative language may simply be for our consideration.

Comment: @RogueJedi - That is for the OP to decide.  I answered the question as it was asked.  In some of these books, the narrator is one of the characters.  In any case, I worded my answer in such a way that it is clear that these words are mentioned.  I don't say "we see an elephant" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Ducks: in *The Phantom Menace* "We will be sitting ducks out here"

A bee seen in *Attack of the Clones* on Naboo

Dogs: "Die Jedi-dogs", C-3PO in *Attack of the Clones*

Names of droids: Vulture Droid, Hyena Droid, Spider Droid, Crab Droid, Scarab Droid.

Hawkeye: name of a clone trooper.

Falcon: *Millennium Falcon*

Given the precedent for animals to be referenced in conversation. (Nerf herder, Bantha podo, kiss a wookie, rip the ears of a gundark, Moof) I would assume that these were left in knowingly.

Comment: As noted in a comment on a previous answer, names and words in speech may simply be [translation convention](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TranslationConvention) without those animals _actually_ being present in the *Star Wars* universe.